# Phaser.js arcade physics overlap not working

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

I have previously succeeded in enabling collision detection using overlaps on phaser arcade physics objects. The collision was between lasers flying at the player and the player. I have modified the game to have multiple "players" that play as simultaneous AIs to dodge the lasers. Instead of having a single player represented as a phaser physics object, I now have an array. But now, my old command doesn't work. For some reason, it thinks that the players and laser (spear) are colliding the moment the laser is created, and they are not. This causes the players to instantly be killed, and I don't understand why. My previous implementation that worked:

```
this.physics.add.overlap(this.player, this.spears[nSpears-1][1], this.die);
```

My current code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < this.players.length; i++){
    if (this.players[i][1] == 'alive'){
        this.physics.add.overlap(this.players[i][0], this.spears[nSpears-1][1], this.die(i));
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you put console log in if and on  this.players array.

Comment: "it thinks that the players and laser [...] are colliding the moment the laser is created, and they are not" You've turned on debugging and confirmed that you don't have overlap? Depending upon how your players and lasers are moving, I could definitely see a few pixel overlap causing this issue.